# Python boolean arrays confusion in jupyter IDE

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean

I am new to boolean arrays and find these statements confusing

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
```

the output of array a is : array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
But when i write down this

```
b = a[True, True, False, False, False]
```

and print the array b using

```
print(b)
```

the output is :

```
[]
```

As far as I understand I want to transfer some elements from array a to array b, but why is b empty?
What is happening in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nested brackets:

```
a = np.arange(5)
b = a[[True, True, False, False, False]]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[0 1]
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. But i want to know why this is so. Why was nesting necessary here?